# SQL Server - having count equal to count of another table confusion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having trouble understanding this basic concept on "having count".

We have two tables as below:

```
declare @t1 table (id int, num int, name varchar(10))
declare @t2 table (id int, name varchar(10))

insert into @t1 values (1, 10, 'a')
insert into @t1 values (2, 20, 'b')
insert into @t1 values (3, 30, 'c')

insert into @t1 values (4, 10, 'a')
insert into @t1 values (5, 20, 'b')

insert into @t1 values (8, 20, 'b')
insert into @t1 values (9, 30, 'c')


insert into @t2 values (10,'a')
insert into @t2 values (20,'b')
insert into @t2 values (30,'c')
```

So they contain:

#### table @t1

```
id      num     name
-----------------------
1       10      a
2       20      b
3       30      c
4       10      a
5       20      b
8       20      b
9       30      c
```

#### table @t2

```
id      name
-------------
10      a
20      b
30      c
```

So now I'm trying to have following result:

#### desired result

```
id      num     name
-----------------------
1       10      a
2       20      b
3       30      c
```

To do so, I wrote these five lines of code:

```
select t1.id, t1.num, t1.name
from @t1 t1
inner join @t2 t2 on t2.name = t1.name
group by t1.id, t1.num, t1.name
having count(*) = (select count(*) from @t2)
```

But something's wrong with this idea and it does not return any row.
What I want is to find three rows of @t1 that contains @t2 name values.

Any idea?

Comment: Whats the logic for getting desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
select t1.id, t1.num, t1.name, nm = count(*)
from @t1 t1
inner join @t2 t2 on t2.name = t1.name
group by t1.id, t1.num, t1.name
```

will give you this result:

```
id  num name cnt
----------------
1   10  a   1
2   20  b   1
3   30  c   1
4   10  a   1
5   20  b   1
8   20  b   1
9   30  c   1
```

as you can see you are trying to find rows where cnt column equals to the overall rows number in table @t2, which is 3. That is why there is no rows in the output. If you want the output described in your question you should write:

```
 ;with cte as
    (
    select t1.id
            , t1.num
            , t1.name
            , rn = row_number() over (partition by t1.name order by t1.id)
    from @t1 t1
    inner join @t2 t2 on t2.name = t1.name
    )
    select id
           , num
           , name
    from cte
    where rn = 1
```

This query uses a common table expression (cte), which is a virtual table, that is stored in operating memory while executing a query, and an over clause, you can read about it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql

```
rn = row_number() over (partition by t1.name order by t1.id)
```

- this expression will number your rows based on t1.name ordered by t1.id.